Random or Unusual microcontroller restarting issue

I am developing a prototype where it takes input from 24V sensor and output to 24V 2.5A solenoid coils controlled by microcontroller ATMEGA2560.
I have mentioned 2 circuits in the image where first circuit converts 24V sensor input to 5V for microcontroller and second circuit converts 5V microcontroller signal to 24V through power relay (G2R-1-E) to 24V 2.5A solenoid coil (which is used to control hydraulic system).
The issue is, in random conditions the microcontroller is getting restart and while testing without any solenoid coil load it is working fine without restart
May be do i have to use 1N4148 diode instead of 1N4007 across the relay to avoid this restarting issue? because i think it is happening because of power sorting between 5V and GND while the relay coil discharge. or is there any other issue?

The second issue is, While the solenoid coil is connected to the relay output side the spark is generating between NO and COM while the relay is power off. Without load there is no spark while switching.

What value varistor?

varistor - 10D431k

"While the solenoid coil is connected to the relay output side the spark is generating between NO and COM while the relay is power off. Without load there is no spark while switching." if the arc persists for more than an instant, then this suggests your relay is not rated appropriately...

"the microcontroller is getting restart and while testing without any solenoid coil load it is working fine without restart" - can you quantify this arc more? is the load inductive, and can you do anything more to quench it properly (powerful arcs can often lead to wear on contacts, and ultimately failure)

i am using G2R-1 5VDC omron 5pin relay

i tried external RC Absorption/Snubber Circuit connected across NO and COM, but the result is same

Again, what value (RC)?

CBB22 630V 104J capacitor, 120 ohm 0.5 watts resistor and 10D431K varistor

If the 24V solenoid has DC coil you can use a freewheel diode to remove the spark.

Using a diode like the 1N4148 across the relay coil is a good idea to suppress back EMF and prevent voltage spikes.

What decoupling capacitors are you using on the microcontroller and where are they? If it is on a prebuilt board they should be there already.

The arcing voltage can be quite low, even 20 or 30V, but most likely is a couple hundred V at this current.
A 400V+ varistor is unsuited to this service; choose a lower rating, or a TVS diode such as 1.5KE36CA.
An RC snubber can also be used, but again needs to be suited to the load.  Notice that, at instant of turn-off, the solenoid's inductance is charged to rated current (2.5A), and that current finds a path through anything it can.  A snubber of 120Ω + 0.1µF will develop an instantaneous voltage drop of 2.5A * 120Ω = 300V, and sparking probably ensues.  The capacitor likewise will charge at a rate of 2.5A / 0.1µF = 25V/µs, so doubles the voltage drop in merely 10µs -- in which time the contacts probably haven't opened very far (mechanical motion is far slower than typical electrical changes are), and breakdown occurs.
Eventually the inductance discharges, current decreases, rate-of-change decreases, and the spark goes out, but this will take at least the better part of a millisecond; the amount of change within tens of microseconds can be ignored, so the above will hold.
Ideally we would choose C = L / R2, where R is the total series resistance (including the coil's, about 10Ω) and L is the solenoid inductance.  This gives critical damping, minimizing voltage overshoot and eliminating ringing.  A ballpark figure for solenoids this size is a few 100 mH, and choosing external R of 10Ω gives a total of 20 or C = (100mH) / (20Ω)2 = 250µF.  Or more, because inductance may be higher than this, particularly in the solenoid-closed position.
We might compromise on this, and allow a somewhat higher turn-off voltage, maybe series resistor up to 39Ω, reducing C to 68µF say, or even less
It still seems unlikely that such a capacitance value would be acceptable for other reasons, so the TVS diode is preferable.  A varistor is less preferable as its breakdown voltage is less well defined, but a 30 to 60V rated part would likely suffice as well.
Note it is a separate issue, that your MCU is resetting due to EMI.  Other connected or nearby equipment will emit sparking noise and is likely to cause exactly the same issue.
